# Backing up Windows drive under Linux OS?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, ubuntu, backup

I have a dual-boot Linux/Windows machine, each having a separate 1TB SSD drive. Mostly Linux is used, Windows just occasionally.

An incremental daily/weekly/monthly backup using [rsnapshot](https://rsnapshot.org/) is set-up on the Linux. Backed up files are stored on the local NAS storage.

Does it make sense to mount Windows SSD drive under Linux and include it in the backup too? Are there serious drawbacks?